# C++ evaluating an expression it shouldn't

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have overidden the `operator|` to act as a filter for a given `vector` and a function, if this function returns a `bool`. In case it doesn't, it calls `for_each` on the `vector`.

```
template<typename T, typename Func>
auto operator | (const vector<T> &v, Func f){
  bool result = is_same<bool, decltype(f(v[0]))>::value;
  vector<T> temp;
  if (result){
    temp.reserve(v.size());
    for(auto itr = v.begin(); itr != v.end(); ++itr){
      bool func_return = f(*itr);
      if (func_return){
        temp.push_back(*itr);
      }
    }
    return temp;
  }
  else{
    for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),f);
    return temp;
  }
}
```

This code works fine when acting as a filter, but the `for_each` part is broken. Whenever I try to run the following code:

```
int main() {
vector<int> v1 = { 2, 9, 8, 8, 7, 4 };
v1 | []( int x ) { return x % 2 == 0; } | [] ( int x ) { cout << x << " "; };
}
```

The compiler returns:

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'bool' with an rvalue of type 'void'
bool func_return = f(*itr);

in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'operator|<int, (lambda at
      main.cpp:44:43)>' requested here
v1 | []( int x ) { return x % 2 == 0; } | [] ( int x ) { cou...
                                        ^
```

Which seem strange to me, after all, the compiler shoudn't be executing that line in the second operator, as `result` should be `false`. Can anyone help me on this one?

Comment: The compiler compiles the both if and else branches. You should use `if constexpr` and C++17.

Comment: `if constexpr` will have the problem that `v[0]` isn't known at compile time. What's a way to check at compile time that `Func` is a function that takes a `T` as an argument and returns a `bool`? Some kind of comparison with an `std::function`?

Comment: Or... I guess we don't actually need to know `v[0]` at compile time, because to get the `decltype` we just need to know the type of `v`, the signature of `vector<T>::operator[]`, and the signature of `f::operator()`, which are all known at compile time. So does that mean it works even with an empty vector?

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes, there's no issue with an empty vector. `v[42]` would be the same thing as `v[0]` inside `decltype`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This lambda:

```
[] ( int x ) { cout << x << " "; }
```

has a `void` return type, so this line:

```
bool func_return = f(*itr);
```

doesn't compile. Since the value of `result` depends only on `Func` and `T`, you have the necessary information to decide whether to execute the `if` branch at compile time. You can use a `constexpr if` instead of a run-time `if`:

```
if constexpr(result)
```

and now the code inside this branch will not be compiled when the function is instantiated with the wrong types.

Also, you need to make `result` a compile time constant to use it in a `if constexpr` condition.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s13x65).